# Test if it is JSONObject or JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I have a json stream which can be something like :

```
{"intervention":

    { 
      "id":"3",
              "subject":"dddd",
              "details":"dddd",
              "beginDate":"2012-03-08T00:00:00+01:00",
              "endDate":"2012-03-18T00:00:00+01:00",
              "campus":
                       { 
                         "id":"2",
                         "name":"paris"
                       }
    }
}
```

or something like

```
{"intervention":
            [{
              "id":"1",
              "subject":"android",
              "details":"test",
              "beginDate":"2012-03-26T00:00:00+02:00",
              "endDate":"2012-04-09T00:00:00+02:00",
              "campus":{
                        "id":"1",
                        "name":"lille"
                       }
            },

    {
     "id":"2",
             "subject":"lozlzozlo",
             "details":"xxx",
             "beginDate":"2012-03-14T00:00:00+01:00",
             "endDate":"2012-03-18T00:00:00+01:00",
             "campus":{
                       "id":"1",
                       "name":"lille"
                      }
            }]
}
```

In my Java code I do the following:

```
JSONObject json = RestManager.getJSONfromURL(myuri); // retrieve the entire json stream     
JSONArray  interventionJsonArray = json.getJSONArray("intervention");
```

In the first case, the above doesn't work because there is only one element in the stream..
How do I check if the stream is an `object` or an `array` ?

I tried with `json.length()` but it didn't work..

Thanks

Comment: please check below link to find the better result  https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener#nextValue

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
JSONObject json;
Object     intervention;
JSONArray  interventionJsonArray;
JSONObject interventionObject;

json = RestManager.getJSONfromURL(myuri); // retrieve the entire json stream     
Object intervention = json.get("intervention");
if (intervention instanceof JSONArray) {
    // It's an array
    interventionJsonArray = (JSONArray)intervention;
}
else if (intervention instanceof JSONObject) {
    // It's an object
    interventionObject = (JSONObject)intervention;
}
else {
    // It's something else, like a string or number
}
```

This has the advantage of getting the property value from the main `JSONObject` just once. Since getting the property value involves walking a hash tree or similar, that's useful for performance (for what it's worth).

Answer (score 13):

Maybe a check like this?

```
JSONObject intervention = json.optJSONObject("intervention");
```

This returns a `JSONObject` or `null` if the intervention object is not a JSON object. Next, do this:

```
JSONArray interventions;
if(intervention == null)
        interventions=jsonObject.optJSONArray("intervention");
```

This will return you an array if it's a valid `JSONArray` or else it will give `null`.

Answer (score 12):

To make it simple, you can just check first string from server result.

```
String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()); //this function produce JSON
String firstChar = String.valueOf(result.charAt(0));

if (firstChar.equalsIgnoreCase("[")) {
    //json array
}else{
    //json object
}
```

This trick is just based on String of JSON format `{foo : "bar"}` (object)
or  `[ {foo : "bar"}, {foo: "bar2"} ]` (array)

Answer (score 7):

You can get the Object of the input string by using below code.

```
String data = "{ ... }";
Object json = new JSONTokener(data).nextValue();
if (json instanceof JSONObject)
 //do something for JSONObject
else if (json instanceof JSONArray)
 //do something for JSONArray
```

Link: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener#nextValue

Comment: This is the best approach in my case, and also handle any response that does not fit into the two object types

Comment: This should be the correct answer, especially if you have a stream of data. Just pull nextValue and test the type.

Answer (score 2):

```
      Object valueObj = uiJSON.get(keyValue);
        if (valueObj instanceof JSONObject) {
            this.parseJSON((JSONObject) valueObj);
        } else if (valueObj instanceof JSONArray) {
            this.parseJSONArray((JSONArray) valueObj);
        } else if(keyValue.equalsIgnoreCase("type")) {
            this.addFlagKey((String) valueObj);
        }
```

// ITERATE JSONARRAY
    private void parseJSONArray(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {
        for (Iterator iterator = jsonArray.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) iterator.next();
            this.parseJSON(object);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tryied it, but maybe...

```
JsonObject jRoot = RestManager.getJSONfromURL(myuri); // retrieve the entire json stream
JsonElement interventionElement = jRoot.get("intervention");
JsonArray interventionList = new JsonArray();

if(interventionElement.isJsonArray()) interventionList.addAll(interventionElement.getAsJsonArray());
else interventionList.add(interventionElement);
```

If it's a JsonArray object, just use getAsJsonArray() to cast it. If not, it's a single element so just add it.

Anyway, your first exemple is broken, you should ask server's owner to fix it. A JSON data structure must be consistent. It's not just because sometime intervention comes with only 1 element that it doesn't need to be an array. If it has only 1 element, it will be an array of only 1 element, but still must be an array, so that clients can parse it using always the same schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //returns boolean as true if it is JSONObject else returns boolean false 
public static boolean returnBooleanBasedOnJsonObject(Object jsonVal){
        boolean h = false;
        try {
            JSONObject j1=(JSONObject)jsonVal;
            h=true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
   if(e.toString().contains("org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to     org.json.simple.JSONObject")){
                h=false;
            }
        }
        return h;

    }
```