# Got JSONObject text must begin with '{' error

Tags: java, json

The error is last line throw JsonException

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(baseUrl+"/jaspertemplate"); 

ClientResponse respons = webResource.accept("application/json")
           .get(ClientResponse.class);

String output = respons.getEntity(String.class);
JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(output.trim());
```

My JSON:

```
[
    {
        "type": "folder",
        "name": "PAM",
        "path": "C:\\home\\sameer\\sample\\PAM",
        "id": "PAM6",
        "c‌​hildren": [
            {
                "type": "file",
                "name": "Country_Report_View_PAM.jasper",
                "path": "C:\\home\\‌​sameer\\sample\\PAM\\Country_Report_View_PAM.jasper",
                "id": "Country_Report_View_PAM.j‌​asper7",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: [{"type":"folder","name":"PAM","path":"C:\\home\\sameer\\sample\\PAM","id":"PAM6","children":[{"type":"file","name":"Country_Report_View_PAM.jasper","path":"C:\\home\\sameer\\sample\\PAM\\Country_Report_View_PAM.jasper","id":"Country_Report_View_PAM.jasper7","children":[]}]}]                         My Json is this

Comment: Should your comment be in the original question?

Comment: are you returning array or object from server side ? if it is array please return object instead

Comment: I don't know your using librairy, but i recomand using gson: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ (free and easy to use)

Comment: If it is a JSON array, use JSONArray() constructor instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys.. from my web service i am using Gson

Comment: String json = gson.toJson(strTemplateChildrens);
  
  return Response.ok().entity(json).build();

Comment: And convert the Json into String and pass the String at my client side ..

Comment: Can someone revert Now please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are expecting a JSONObject but it is returning a JSONArray. 
Please check object's validity before use.
Following post can be used to check JSONObject or JSONArray:
[Test if it is JSONObject or JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988287/test-if-it-is-jsonobject-or-jsonarray)