# How to handle Retrofit JSON dynamically

Tags: android, json, dynamic

I'm getting following JSON response:
"data" in object:

```
"status": true,
"data":{
    //Some data
}
```

Sometimes it comes in array as:

```
"status": true,
"data":[
    //Some data
]
```

How to check data's response dynamically that, is object or array?
*I'm using Retrofit

My Retrofit parsing for array as:

```
@SerializedName("data")
ArrayList<DataDetail> dataList;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine whether JSON is a JSONObject or JSONArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118708/determine-whether-json-is-a-jsonobject-or-jsonarray).

Comment: I think you are not able to manage this all because everything is happening related to json parsing in background for your retrofit. So where you will check for instanceof. You have to change your retrofit structure.

Comment: Yes, i'm facing exactly same problem. @Ready Android

Comment: Kindly check updated question @Ready Android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the Json is unknown that whether it will be JsonObject or JsonArray, then simply use JsonElement like below:

```
@SerializedName("data")
private JsonElement data;
```

Now to convert this JsonElement to your respective model as per your requirement you can use below code:

```
if(data instanceOf JsonObject){
    YourModelForData object = YourDataComponentForObject(data);
    // Do anything with Object
} else {
    List<YourModelForData> array = YourDataComponentForArray(data);
    // Do anything with array
}

public YourModelForData YourDataComponentForObject(JsonElement data) {
     Type type = new TypeToken<YourModelForData>() {
     }.getType();
     YourModelForData item = new Gson().fromJson(data, type);
}

public List<YourModelForData> YourDataComponentForArray(JsonElement data) {
      Type type = new TypeToken<List<YourModelForData>>() {
      }.getType();
      List<YourModelForData> items = new Gson().fromJson(data, type);
}
```

Happy Coding <{}>;

Comment: this method is returning only list but what about when only object comes ?

Comment: I have edited my answer, Please try that. Because check of object or array you have to maintain using instanceof and let the JsonElement handle the serialise datatype. You can also typecast json using getAsJsonObject or getAsJsonArray using gson.

Comment: Look good !!, but where to call above method, and what it will return ? @Siraj Sumra

Comment: Edited the answer. Use it that way. Try to use the object and array according to your requirement as per edited answer. Hope it help

Comment: Object parsing worked but having some problem with array, Error getting as: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Comment: You can typecast the JsonElement with getAsJsonArray. Try using it. Also try to give condition as else if(data instanceof JsonArray). Hope it works

Answer (score 2):

```
JSONObject json;
Object     intervention;
JSONArray  interventionJsonArray;
JSONObject interventionObject;

json = RestManager.getJSONfromURL(myuri); // retrieve the entire json stream     
Object intervention = json.get("intervention");
if (intervention instanceof JSONArray) {
    // It's an array
    interventionJsonArray = (JSONArray)intervention;
}
else if (intervention instanceof JSONObject) {
    // It's an object
    interventionObject = (JSONObject)intervention;
}
else {
    // It's something else, like a string or number
}
```

check this thread
[Test if it is JSONObject or JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988287/test-if-it-is-jsonobject-or-jsonarray)